# Mongo Query to Join two collection and get Sum of the particular field - MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo-3.x

I am having two collection `post`, `comment`.

`post` collection data,

```
[
  {
    _id: "2218457a-4b5d-4f77-a27f-9546099202df",
    author: "tes1@gmail.com",
    description: "Some description",
    total_votes: 10
  },
  {
    _id: "2218457a-565-4f77-a27f",
    author: "tes1@gmail.com",
    description: "Second description",
    total_votes: 20
  },
  {
    _id: "2218457a-4b5d-4f77-23das",
    author: "tes2@gmail.com",
    description: "Some description",
    total_votes: 5
  },
 {
    _id: "2218457a-232dd-4f77-23das",
    author: "tes3@gmail.com",
    description: "Some description",
    total_votes: 10
  },
]
```

`comment` collection data,

```
[
  {
    _id: "2218457a-12312",
    author: "tes1@gmail.com",
    description: "Some description",
    total_votes: 5
  },
  {
    _id: "2218457a-56sd5",
    author: "test2@gmail.com",
    description: "Second Comment",
    total_votes: 5
  },
  {
    _id: "2218457a-4b5d-4f77-23das",
    author: "tes2@gmail.com",
    description: "Third Comment",
    total_votes: 5
  }
]
```

I want to get the  sum of `total_votes` based on the `author`.

I need the output as below,

```
[
 {
   author: "test1@gmail.com",
   total_votes: 35
 },
 {
   author: "test2@gmail.com",
   total_votes: 15
 },
 {
   author: "test3@gmail.com",
   total_votes: 10
 }
]
```

Kindly provide the mongo query for my expected result.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I presume your main struggle is how to combine the sum from 2 collections. You may use `$unionWith` for this. For a specific author's records, you may consider a more performant way of matching them in early stage.

```js
db.post.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "author": "tes1@gmail.com"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unionWith": {
      "coll": "comment",
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            "author": "tes1@gmail.com"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$author",
      total_votes: {
        $sum: "$total_votes"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/K6F7pw5eu0X) for your reference.

Comment: Thanks. It works fine. but when I want filter based on "author",  how do change the query. say for example, I want get total_votes for author "test1@gmail.com" ?

Comment: @MOHAMEDAZARUDEEN updated the answer to reflect the change. A general rule for performant mongodb aggregation is try to make intermediate result set as small as possible, so I put the `$match` stages earlier.